# How to use an osciloscope with a FPGA using Vhdl

Tags: vhdl

Any of you have any material about this?

I want to show an std_logic_vector(0 to 29) on the osciloscope

Comment: this is a question for [Electrical Engineering](http://electronics.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 1):

That's 30 bits ... you don't want to probe 30 pins.

I'd use 2 spare pins and roll a simple serial interface off a suitable (e.g. 1 MHz) clock and a /32 counter.

One pin shifts out each bit according to the count, the other is set when you send the first bit, as a convenient triggering signal.

Either let it free run, or tell it to start (inside the FPGA) every time you update that signal.

Comment: No but it should be dead easy to write.

Answer (score 0):

Most FPGA vendors provide some kind of in-system debugger (like ChipScope for Xilinx ISE designs). These provide a very powerful debugging perspective for your FPGA design and allow you to record waveforms on hundreds of signals.